# Reinstalling application with same digital signature fails to access user data

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I have an application which is signed by using the signing process described here http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html. This application stores its data in a folder /data/data/mystorage/. After I install a new version of the application which is signed by using the same key the new version is not able to access the folder /data/data/mystorage. What am I missing here? From what I know the applications signed with the same certificate are supposed to be provided the same application id and hence can access previously stored data by the user. How to make sure that the application can access the data even after reinstall?

Comment: **/data/data/mystorage/** - Is that the actual path you are using or is that just an example?

Comment: No the actual path is actually /data/foobar/. I am working with a rooted device and the application is reinstalled using the adb shell commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure both apps have same shared user id in the manifest:

```
android:sharedUserId="com.your.app"
```

Comment: The package name of my application is "com.stw.foobar". Both the applications have the same package name. Even after having the same packaage name would this step be required? If yes should my entry in the manifest read as android:sharedUserId="com.stw.foobar"?

Comment: Yes, i think it is still needed. It doesn't matter what you write inside `sharedUserId` as long as they are same in both manifests. So `android:sharedUserId="com.stw.foobar"` is ok.

Comment: Thanks Man. I will quickly try it out and then up vote your answer. Thanks again. :)

Comment: I hope it fixes the problem :)